# Extend ctypes to specify field overloading

Tags: python, metaprogramming, ctypes, metaclass, telemetry

I would like to extend ctypes Structure, BigEndianStructure, LittleEndianStructure.

The ability to specify each field to have a description, and overload how the variable is returned to possibly enum, polyco, etc attributes.

Something like the following is what I would like to do, but am not sure how to make the ModifedCTypesStructure parent class.

My goal is to use this for commanding / telemetry of binary data.

```
class Color(Enum): 
     RED = 1
     GREEN = 2
     BLUE = 3

class Packet(ModifedCTypesStructure):
   __fields__ = [("fieldA",ctypes.c_int32,
                    {"brief":"""Description of fieldA""",
                     "enum":Color}
                 ),
                 ("fieldB",ctypes.c_uint32, 
                     {"repr":lambda x: hex(x)}
                 )
                ]

 a = Packet()
 help(a.fieldA)
 > Description of fieldA
 a.fieldA = Color.RED
print a._fieldA # Return the binary field
> 1
a.fieldB = 0xbb
print a.fieldB
> 0xbb #Note repr is called to return '0xbb'
print a._fieldB
> 187
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible - 
most of the magic provided by `ctypes.Structure` is due to its fields being "descriptors" - i.e. objects that follow [Python's descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) - analog to what we get when we use the `@property` decorator in a class body.

`ctypes.Structure` has a metaclass that is responsible to convert each field listed in the special cased  variable name `_fields_` into a `_ctypes.CField` object (you can check that by verifying the result of `type(mystryct.field)` in an interactive Python prompt.

Therefore, in order to extend the behavior for the fields themselves, we'd need to extend this `CField` class - and modify the metaclass that creates your Strutcture to use our fields.  The CField class seems to be a normal Python class itself - so it is easy to modify, if we respect the call to the super-methods.

*however* there are some catches in your "wishlist":

1. using "help" requires the Python object to have the help string embedded in its class `__doc__` attribute (not the instance). So we can do that each time the field itself is retrieved from the structure class, we ceae dynamically a new class with the required help.
2. When retrieving a value from an object, Python can't "know" in advance if the value will be used just for being "viewed" by `repr` or will actually be used. Therefore we either customize the value that is returned by `a.fieldB` for one that have a custom representation or we don't do it at all. The code bellow *does* create a dynamic class on field retrieval that will have a custom representation, and try to preserve all other numeric properties of the underlying value. But that is set to be both slow and may present some incompatibilities - you may choose to turn that off when not debugging values, or simply get the raw value.
3. Ctype's "Fields" will of course have some internal structure of their own, like the offset for each memory position and so on - thus, I'd suggest the following approach:(1) create a new "Field" class that does not inherit from ctypes.Field at all - and that implement the enhancements you want; (2) Upon ModifiedStructure creation create all the "_" prefixed names, and pass these for the original Ctypes.Structure metaclass to create its fields as it always does; (3) make our "Field" class read and write to the original ctypes.Fields, and have their custom transforms and representations.

As you can see, I also took care of actually transforming Enum values upon writting.

To try everything, just inherit from "ModifiedStructure" bellow, instead of `ctypes.Structure`:

```
from ctypes import Structure
import ctypes


class A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", ctypes.c_uint8)]

FieldType = type(A.a)
StructureType = type(A)

del A


def repr_wrapper(value, transform):
    class ReprWrapper(type(value)):
        def __new__(cls, value):
            return super().__new__(cls, value)
        def __repr__(self):
            return transform(self)

    return ReprWrapper(value)


def help_wrapper(field):
    class Field2(field.__class__):
        __doc__ = field.help

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.__doc__

    return Field2(field.name, field.type_, help=field.help, repr=field.repr, enum=field.enum)


class Field:
    def __init__(self, name, type_, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.type_ = type_
        self.real_name = "_" + name
        self.help = kwargs.pop("brief", f"Proxy structure field {name}")
        self.repr = kwargs.pop("repr", None)
        self.enum = kwargs.pop("enum", None)
        if self.enum:
            self.rev_enum =  {constant.value:constant for constant in self.enum.__members__.values() }

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return help_wrapper(self)

        value = getattr(instance, self.real_name)
        if self.enum:
            return self.rev_enum[value]
        if self.repr:
            return repr_wrapper(value, self.repr)

        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self.enum:
            value = getattr(self.enum, value.name).value
        setattr(instance, self.real_name, value)


class ModifiedStructureMeta(StructureType):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        _fields = namespace.get("_fields_", "")
        classic_fields = []
        for field in _fields:
            # Create the set of descriptors for the new-style fields:
            name = field[0]
            namespace[name] = Field(name, field[1], **(field[2] if len(field) > 2 else {}))
            classic_fields.append(("_" + name, field[1]))

        namespace["_fields_"] = classic_fields
        return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)


class ModifiedStructure(ctypes.Structure, metaclass=ModifiedStructureMeta):
    __slots__ = ()
```

And testing it on the interactive prompt:

```
In [165]: class A(ModifiedStructure):
     ...:     _fields_ = [("b", ctypes.c_uint8, {"enum": Color, 'brief': "a color", }), ("c", ctypes.c_uint8, {"repr": hex})]
     ...:     
     ...:     

In [166]: a = A()

In [167]: a.c = 20

In [169]: a.c
Out[169]: 0x14

In [170]: a.c = 256

In [171]: a.c
Out[171]: 0x0

In [172]: a.c = 255

In [173]: a.c
Out[173]: 0xff

In [177]: a.b = Color.RED

In [178]: a._b
Out[178]: 1

In [180]: help(A.b)
(shows full Field class help starting with the given description)

In [181]: A.b
Out[181]: a color
```

Comment: If you were going to inherit from both the BigEndianStructure, and the LittleEndianStructure would you just make a ModifiedStructureMetaLE, and a ModifiedStructureMetaBE?  I was trying to read through the ctypes code, and its all in C.

Comment: You will need to create one more metaclass  - just check the return of  `type (ctypes.LittleEndianStructure)`  and the same for BigEndian - you will see that there are two separate metaclasses . No code change i necessary, jsut changing from whic metaclass the custom metaclass inherits is enough. The "Field" class I created should work for all three, though.

Comment: How would you handle bitfields ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with after playing around with metaclasses for a while. I haven't ever used them so I wasnt sure if this was the correct approach.

I couldnt figure out the repr thing.  Im going to play around with your solution @jsbueno.

I ended up building and appending properties to the classes on creation.
Everything i read was saying not to use metaclasses 99% of the time so kind of wondering if I was going down the wrong path.

Also I wanted to use the same metaclass for BigEndian / LittleEndian structures forgot to add that to the wish list.

```
import ctypes



def make_fget(key,enum=None):
    def fget(self):
        res = getattr(self,  key)
        if enum != None:
            res = enum(res)
        return res
    return fget
def make_fset(key):
    def fset(self, value):
        if isinstance(value,Enum):
            value = value.value        
        setattr(self, key, value)
    return fset

class PyGndTlmMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls,name,bases, dct):
        endian = ctypes.Structure
        if '_endian_' in dct:
            endian = dct['_endian_']
        if not endian in [ctypes.Structure, ctypes.LittleEndianStructure, ctypes.BigEndianStructure]:
            pass #TODO throw error

        fields = []
        attributes = dct.copy()

        for f in dct['_fields_']:
            fname = '_' + f[0]
            ftype = f[1]
            res = (fname,ftype)
            specs = {}
            #If 3rd argument is an integer than we are dealing with bitfields
            if len(f)   >= 3 and type(f[2]) == int:
                res = (fname,ftype,f[2])
            elif len(f) >= 3 and type(f[2]) == dict:
                specs = f[2]
            elif len(f) >= 4 and type(f[3]) == dict:
                specs = f[3]
            fields.append(res)

            enum = None
            if "enum" in specs:
                enum = specs['enum']            
            fget = make_fget(fname,enum=enum)
            fset = make_fset(fname)

            doc = "Not Set"
            if "brief" in specs:
                doc = specs["brief"]

            if "enum" in specs:
                #TODO use different getter/setter
                pass
            attributes[f[0]] = property(fget, fset,doc=doc)

        attributes['_fields_'] = fields

        bases = (endian,)

        x = type(name, bases, attributes)
        return x

from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

class Packet( ):
    __metaclass__ = PyGndTlmMeta
    _endian_ = ctypes.BigEndianStructure
    _fields_ = [
                ("a",ctypes.c_byte,{"brief":"testing"}),
                ("b",ctypes.c_int, {"enum":Color})
                ]


x = Packet()
```